# Term for multiple strings finger picked simultaneously

Tags: guitar

Forgive the noob question.

Is there a term for finger picking multiple strings simultaneously?

For example if you play the 4th string and 1st string at the exact same time versus 1st string then 4th string.

Comment: I don't think this question is clear enough. Despite the "guitar" tag, I read it initially as a general music question, with the answer being "chord", or "dyad" for the example given (making Carl Witthoft's answer not unreasonable). If it's about guitar, is it about left or right hand technique? OP is specific about "finger picking", but MattPutnam's answer is about the left hand. A "double stop" on guitar is still a double stop even if you bow it Jimmy Page style.

Comment: @Bacs - it's about guitar - see the tag. Lh or rh techniques are irrelevant.It's about two or more notes being played at the same time,as is entirely possible on guitar.Everything seems very clear in the phrasing of the question. Matt's answer is not only about the l.h. It's about note production. This is a very simple question that's produced ridiculous results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Multiple stops", or specifically, "double stops", "triple stops", etc.  Borrowed from orchestral string terminology.

Comment: Wonder why the 'stop' word is used. It hints at notes being fingered, but also is used when open strings are played simultaneously.

Comment: maybe from the Organ Stops? Double stops is two voices?

Comment: This is both wrong and doesn't address the question.  There are multiple ways to play triple or quadruple stops on a bowed instrument.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - did you misread the question?

Comment: @Tim no, did you?  I'm an experienced cellist, and I can tell you there are many ways to perform a triple-stop.   I think the OP is better served with analogies to piano chords vs. arpeggios.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - on guitar, which has all 6 strings virtually on the same plane, unlike cello, violin, etc., several can be plucked simultaneously with the digits of, usually, the right hand. If I was to be 'picky', I'd say by using a spare finger from the fretting hand, all 6 can be played simultaneously, as in 6-stopped. Arpeggios are certainly not what this question is about.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I'm not talking about string technique at all.  Playing two notes simultaneously on guitar is called a double stop, and that's a term that's borrowed from strings.  I don't understand what you're complaining about.

Comment: Then please change your wording to state (correctly) that " X stops" is borrowed from organ music, which is in fact the source.  String players borrowed it as well.

Comment: Taking it a little further, originally it referred to the violin family, played bowed, with adjacent strings, neither of which was open. I think we've just bastardised it for guitar . And, sorry, Carl, you appear to be barking. Up the wrong tree!

Comment: This whole discussion is completely ridiculous and completely off-topic.  OP asked what the technique is called.  It's called double/multiple stops.  Also, I find it dubious that the term comes from organ: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_stop

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak directly to markings in guitar music, but the good old standby [dolmetsch symbols page](http://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm) will show you a vertical wiggly line for "arpeggio."  This symbol specifies that the notes are to be played in sequence rather than simultaneously.  Playing all notes in a chord simultaneously is the default whenever there are multiple notes on the same beat.
[image: arpeggio]

Comment: This answer is addressing notes that are played consecutively, as one would on violin, for example. Consecutive isn't simultaneous, so the wavy 'arp' sign cannot be the solution. On guitar, up to six notes can be played simultaneously, and I'm not talking strumming, which is essentially a fast arp.

Comment: @Tim well, the six (or twelve) strings can be played pseudosimultaneously unless you have more than five fingers, in which case you could truly pluck them all simultaneously.

Comment: o.k., I'll settle for 5 strings!

Comment: @Tim :-) :-)  ....